# Followed the procedure to get SIFT features using jFeatureLib but getting empty .csv

Tags: java, image-processing, feature-extraction, sift

I want to extract SIFT values.
I have followed the instructions from
https://github.com/locked-fg/JFeatureLib/wiki/HowTo

I have
JFeatureLib-1.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Downloaded the sift binary
have book.pgm
kept the jar and sift binary in

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin`

and kept book.pgm as in source folder
I also edited the properties of jar and set path to `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/sift.exe`.
I have also checked the permissions.

I am running following command:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin>java -jar JFeatureLib-1.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar -D Sift -d D:\images\ -o D:\output.csv
```

I am not getting any error but output.csv is empty and does not show any output.

Please help on this.
Am I missing something?
Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Put sift.exe in the same folder that you are running the jar. Set the path to it in jfeaturelib.properties: features.sift.binary=sift.exe. This should work.

Comment: You could modify your answer to sound more certain. It sounds like you aren't _entirely_ sure your solution works.